# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Appcenter Application icon shows up blurry

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I generated iOS build from my worklight project and uploaded to IBM Application Center. I have added icon.png 128x128 resolution and thumbnail.png 90x90 in my common\images folder.

In application center it display a blurry icon with resolution 57x57. I am not sure how application center take the reference of the icon from .IPA file. Please share your suggestion.

Note: In Worklight Console, app icon displays perfect, no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight Console and the Application Center management console are 2 separate entities.

When you deploy the .wlapp file - you essentially deploy it to the Worklight Server > database. The Worklight Console in turn receives from the server the data you then see in the console, including the common\images\thumbnail.png image for the application. That is not the same as the app icon.

In contrast, to the Application Center management console (server > database...) you are deploying the .ipa file that Xcode generated for you - that's very much different from the .wlapp file previously mentioned.

Please make sure you are providing in your application app icons with the correct filenames, [per the guidelines from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/qa/qa1686/_index.html), for example:

57x57 Icon.png
114x114 Icon@2x.png
72x72 Icon-72.png
144x144 Icon-72@2x.png

Comment: Hi Idan, In application installed on device, icons looks perfect. Only in Application Center Console, it displays fuzzy. I inspected the element in browser, for that particular application, it shows an icon image of 57x57. I inspected some of the other applications published in the same app center. It shows 114x114 icon file perfect. I added an icon file with 114x114 resolution and named it as icon.png. Still load same fuzzy icon in application center console. I feel, its because of my image. not sure wats the dpi and resolution that app center console search in .ipa file and load in console.

Comment: Creating a PMR for the same. Thanks

Comment: If this is because of your image, why the PMR...?

Comment: To know from the product team, that the resolution and dpi required to add in Xcode project, that will load perfect in IBM Application Center Console. And why it loads different resolution images for various apps. 57x57, 114x114. How to give a proper reference.

Comment: Lets wait a bit - let me see if I can get an answer internally.

Comment: BTW, make sure your icons are named properly - every icon needs to have a specific filename

Comment: Sure. i am also trying. Named the image as icon.png 114x114 72dpi for iOS.

Comment: See my edited answer with link and correct filenames to use for the application app icons in various sizes.

Comment: @PVR, if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.